# Why to use log while calculating probability of an email being spam?

Tags: classification, naive-bayes, logarithm

I worked on a basic spam email project (Naive Bayes classifier with Laplace smoothing). 
In source code, to calculate probabilities of spam or ham, log of the final result is being used.
Why is it required to take a log?
Theoretically, it is 
[image: PRobability that a word is spam]

But in the source code, the same was calculated this way:

```
for word in processed_message:                
        if word in self.prob_spam:
            pSpam += log(self.prob_spam[word])
        else:
            if self.method == 'tf-idf':
                pSpam -= log(self.sum_tf_idf_spam + len(list(self.prob_spam.keys())))
        if word in self.prob_ham:
            pHam += log(self.prob_ham[word])
        else:
            if self.method == 'tf-idf':
                pHam -= log(self.sum_tf_idf_ham + len(list(self.prob_ham.keys()))) 
        pSpam += log(self.prob_spam_mail)
        pHam += log(self.prob_ham_mail)
    return pSpam >= pHam
```

In this code, inside the for loop, why is the logarithm of prob_spam(word) is taken ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, when you multiply dozens of small probabilities, there is a high chance of overflow in floating points. Taking the logarithm and summing them is a very powerful and practical approach. In addition, since the logarithm is monotonically increasing, you can still compare quantities as if they are in their original domain, i.e. $x<y\rightarrow \log x<\log y$